# add listener for (window.physicalSize.width) to detect browser width web development with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html, dart-webui

how  it possible to add "window.physicalSize.width"  to detect any change in browser "chrome" should notify me ?

the "MediaQuery.of(context).size.width" does not work with flutter web .

any help will be apricated .

regards

Comment: thank you for your replay , but still not work with web ,, but ios and android work fine

Comment: What do you mean "MediaQuery.of(context).size.width" does not work with flutter web?